# Converting date string to Date issue in Swift 3

Tags: swift3, nsdate, nsdateformatter, uidatepicker, xcode8

I have seen many threads for converting Date string to Date, but nothing worked for me. Below is what I am trying to do.

I have a UIDatePicker and I am am trying to get the selected Date and Time. I am getting the correct Date but time is not correct. The problem is with timezone. Given below the code I using.

```
let abbreviation = TimeZone.current.abbreviation() //Without this also same issue happens

let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale.current
dateFormatter.timeZone = NSTimeZone.init(abbreviation: abbreviation!) as TimeZone!
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"

let selectedDateStr = dateFormatter.string(from: self.timePicker.date) //Prints: "2017-04-20 07:50:40"

let selectedDateFromStr = dateFormatter.date(from: selectedDateStr)! as Date as NSDate //Prints: "2017-04-20 02:20:40 +0000"
```

How do I get the correct time, without timezone issue?

**Here is the actual scenario - updated:**

I want to let the user to set time for alarm. I have two views, one is for selecting the time from timepicker and other is for showing the list of alarm times.

If I select a time from picker and show it in alarms list, it will always show current time. Using the code given above.
But if I kill the app and reopen again, it will show the correct time!

What is happening here?

Comment: The date is correct. The output of `print`ing a `Date` is always UTC. Btw: Don't use the Foundation classes with `NS` Prefix in Swift 3. Use the native structs (`Locale`, `TimeZone`, `Date`)

Comment: I got it. But how do I get the correct time?

Comment: The date formatter gives you the correct time. If you convert `selectedDateFromStr` back to `Date` it will be the same as `self.timePicker.date`. A `Date` is a moment in time ( a `Double`) which is the difference to an UTC reference date. It does not contain time zone or locale information. Do your date math with the *raw* `Date` object and use the formatter for human readable representations.

Comment: With Swift 2.x version, it was working fine. I just take datepicker value, and it was valid. After updating to Swift 3 only, the issue started. Actually I wanted to assign datepicker value to a alarm 'time'. Now it shows wrong time. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Your date is correct. BTW no need to mess with the timezone. DateFormatter default timezone is the current timezone. You can verify the resulting date using the same dateFormatter to get the string again. `dateFormatter.string(from: selectedDateFromStr)`

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: Have you solved your issue. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        var dateFormatters = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatters.locale = Locale.current
        dateFormatters.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        dateFormatters.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let selectedDateStr = dateFormatters.string(from: self.timePicker.date)
        let selectedDateFromStr = dateFormatters.date(from: selectedDateStr)!
```

you are casting dateformatter  timezone to string.

Comment: Still no change. This is what I got. 2017-04-20 04:50:35 +0000
  - timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate : 514356635.0

Comment: Updated my question.